# Pycharm cannot stop at breakpoint when there is a infinite recursion exception

Tags: debugging, recursion, pycharm, breakpoints

Below is my source code:

```
def infinite_recursion(i):
    return infinite_recursion(i)


def index_out_of_range():
    arr = [1, 2, 3]
    print arr[3]


def foo():
    try:
        infinite_recursion(1)
    except:
        pass

    print 1


def bar():
    try:
        index_out_of_range()
    except:
        pass

    print 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

When I try to debug it with Pycharm, I set a breakpoint at the line '**print 1**' in the function '**foo**'. Then I execute debug process in Pycharm, finally, it does not stop at the breakpoint, that's very strange.

Then I change my source code and set the breakpoint at the line '**print 2**' in the function '**bar**' and change some source code from

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

to

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar()
```

This time Pycharm can stop at the breakpoint.

Can anybody figure the root cause? It seems Pycharm debugger is out of work after the infinite recursion exception.

Comment: Hum, indeed I reproduced this in `Python 3`: running the code in normal mode does print `1` in the console, while running it in debug leads to `Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.` It might have something to do with the debugger adding extra calls in the stack, making it overflow before the `maximum recursion` depth is reached. Anyway, beyond the curiosity, I hope we agree you should fix your code instead of trying to recover from that.

Comment: My Python version is 2.7.10, and when debug these code it won't raise the error message as Python 3 did. It just keeps going and print `1` to the console. You are right I should fix my code to avoid the infinite recursive, but this code is just a sample to reproduce the issue. The actual code is very complex and hard to detect the infinite recursive. I hope Pycharm can fix this in the future.